# Select em Milhões de Registros SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Bom dia,

Possuo uma base de dados com mais de 11 milhões de registros, quando eu faço um select em cima das duas tabelas para trazer os registros a  consulta demora muito,
Gostaria de saber como poderia melhorar essas performance...

Atualmente com esse select ele traz praticamente 11 milhões de Registros em 1:04s mas preciso deixar mais rápido ainda.

```
SELECT 'SMS'                    as Tipo
      ,convert(date, dataenvio) as Data
      ,descCampanha             as Campanha
      ,1                        as Qtd
  from      tblMensagem t1 with(nolock) 
 inner join tblCampanha t2 with(nolock) on t1.codCampanha = t2.codCampanha
```

Comment: Esse `CONVERT` está a prejudicar a consulta, veja se pode evitar isso. Não existe nenhum filtro que possa aplicar? A coluna `codCampanha` em ambas as tabelas está indexado?

Comment: @LucianoRamos Inicie a otimização analisando o plano de execução da consulta. Nele é possível encontrar possíveis gargalos. Às vezes é somente uma questão de estatísticas desatualizadas.

Comment: @JoséDiz o que eu poderia fazer para melhorar?

Comment: Qual o objetivo ? Existe a necessidade de se usar os 11mi de registros ?

Comment: @Motta Sim, por conta que sera real time

Comment: Você vai trabalhar com os 11 milhões de registros? Para que? Exibir? Repense sua solução pois você vai entupir sua conexão.